# How do I show the number of open cases in a service cloud console?

Tags: servicecloud, service-cloud-console

I'm setting up a Service Cloud Console, for email support. This would replace our current 'system', which is just emailing using outlook.

One feature I can see that support agents will miss is that in outlook, you can easily see if there are any new things (unread emails, so the folder will be shown bold and show the number). I can't see any way to get something similar in a service cloud console.

I have set up case views, one for each of the different types of cases, plus one for 'my cases', but I see no way to show a list of these in any way that would show how many open cases are waiting in each one? All I have is the default dropdown that then shows the cases for that view, but that would mean support agents would need to check a bunch of lists, like the view with normal cases, the view with high priority cases, the view with their own cases, ... just to know if there is anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a custom component, that is a VF page with a count refreshed via poller every x seconds. Then you'd have your metrics in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Dashboards to generate this metric. You can generate a Report on Cases for the various criteria (open cases, closed cases, pending cases, new today, etc). Then you can create a Dashboard which uses that report. Then you should display that Dashboard to your service cloud users so they can see those metrics.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113375&language=en_US

Comment: Caveat: dashboards get stale because they do not automatically refresh (without a scheduled job.)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to refresh dashboards enough that this will more or less show how many cases are open like outlook would show emails? Say refresh them every 5 or 10 minutes?